# How to concatenate part of three layers in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I can use `keras.layers.concatenate` to concatenate two layers then send them to next layer, but if I want to take part of two layers then concatenate them and then send them to next layer, what should I do?

For example, I want to take part of first conv layer and part of the second conv layer and the last pooling layer, and then concatenate them together to form one layer. But Keras is a high level library, how do we take part of them?

You can understand me better by looking at the Figure 2 in paper [A Network-based End-to-End Trainable Task-oriented Dialogue System](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~sjy/papers/wgmv17.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can slice them as you want, like the way you would slice a numpy array or a Python list, and use `K.concatenate`, all in a `Lambda` layer. For example:

```
from keras import backend as K

# ...
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.concatenate([x[0][:,:10],
                                      x[1][:,:10],
                                      x[2][:,:10]], axis=the_concat_axis))([conv1, conv2, pool])
```

Note that the first axis is the batch axis, so you may want to keep all of it (i.e. use `:` as above).